# numpy and matplotlib entry point error in anaconda windows 64 bit

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [2,3,4,5,7,9,13,15,17]
plt.plot(x)
plt.ylabel('Sunlight')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

while executing this in anaconda I got the error

> Entry Point Not Found:"The procedure entry point
>   mkl_aa_fw_get_max_memory could not be located in the dynamic link
>   library mkl_core.dll"

Can anyone please tell how to resolve the issue

Comment: I resolve it update mkl_core.dll in system 32 that's it